# Rectangle on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, rectangles

I'm developing application for WP and I have used Rectangle control to draw line which separated elements of the ListBox.

But I found this text on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.rectangle%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) page:

```
Silverlight for Windows Phone
Supported in: Windows Phone OS 7.1, Windows Phone OS 7.0
```

And my application will be worked on WP8 too.

I don't have possibility to check is Rectangle works on WP8. **So is it work?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `Rectangle` Silverlight XAML control works just fine on WP8.

This is what I've used in my application - running both WP7 and WP8:

```xml
<StackPanel Margin="20,20,20,20" Tap="PodcastGroupTapped">
    <Rectangle Width="175" Height="175" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" />
    <Border Background="Black" Width="175" Height="75" Margin="0,-75,0,0" Opacity="0.7">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle3Style}"/>
    </Border>
</StackPanel>
```

Unfortunately what I've found out is that the docs for WP are not always up to date. It's just better to test and see :)

Answer (score 1):

**Yes it will.**

If you're developing a Windows Phone 7 app, 99% of the time it will function on Windows Phone 8 with no problems. The only caveats to watch out for are listed on [App platform compatibility page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206947%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Obviously, you should try and run your app on either the Windows Phone 8 emulator (part of the WP8 SDK) or on an actual WP8 device. Nokia also has a [Remote Device Access](https://developer.nokia.com/Devices/Remote_device_access/) programme, which is free to use if you [sign up as a Nokia Developer](https://www.developer.nokia.com/Profile/Join.xhtml) - it's very useful if you don't have a WP8 device or Windows 8.